# Screw type for hard to get at place?

Tags: windows, screws, fans

I am going to be attaching a piece of wood to a thin window sash in order to attach a rather heavy window fan to it. I will be using a wood screw to attach the fan housing to the strip of wood (I cannot attach the fan housing to the window sash directly since the wood needs to be wider - and I want to avoid doing damage to the sash, if possible; I hope I'm using term sash correctly: the side strips of wood that the window frame is attached to).

The problem that I see is that the space between the screw head and the fan is essentially nothing (maybe a 1/2") - not enough room to use a standard screwdriver to access it.  Since I may want to take the fan out annually, I need a screw that can be accessed fairly easily.

How wide should the strip of wood be to accommodate this screw that you suggest, and the weight and vibration of the fan? Last question, what type of nail/screw or whatever should I use to attach the strip of wood to the molding?

I want to install this fan in the window - so the window can be closed (the typical installation for this type of whole house fan). I must leave a 1/4" gap between the vinyl window and any screws that go into the frame (in order to avoid damaging the integrity/warranty of the window and allowing space for the lip of the window for opening/closing).

I thought attaching a piece of wood to the sash (inner) would be better than trying to reverse the shields and try to attach it to the outside molding because the storm shields would leave a gap; this loses the efficiency of a whole house fan if there is a gap.

Because of the weight of the fan (and its top heaviness from the motor) I plan to put at least an 8" board on the window ledge to help it from falling and putting too much stress on the rest of the  attachment points - with the vibrations and all. And legs, if needed. I've seen others make a box but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks, much!

[image: fan]

[image: drawing]

[image: sash]

[image: ledge]

Comment: If you have only 1/2" clearance, then your maximum screw length is 1/2" even if you could drive it with a wrench, like a carriage bolt. Would this even get through your wood & hold a fan? I think we need pictures of this location & proposed components to see if a better solution can be found.

Comment: Unless you drive the screw in at an angle, then your best bet is to use a bolt and nut.  Drill the hole for the bolt, put bolt in from underneath, and attach the nut.

Comment: Pictures and/or drawing would be helpful. This may also be a situation where you're better to concentrate on "how do I do the **actual thing I am are trying to do**" rather than "how do I do **the difficult way I  have thought of to do it**" Sash is generally a movable part of the window, though "sash strip" may be the part of window frame you are thinking of - disambiguated by an annotaed picture - I'm ok with screws here, not here" or the like. [Edit] to add those.

Comment: These are all good points.  I think I need to go back to 'the drawing board'.  I hadn't thought about my size restrictions. Lol!  I'll add pics once I re-evaluate your thoughts to consider - if it is even possible.  Thanks!!!

Comment: If you can give us enough in pictures or drawings to see "what you have and what you don't want holes in (and where holes are OK)" we might well be able to come up with a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Ecnerwal - and all the others.  I'll draw up some details/ photos for you pros tomorrow and see what you think.  The concept seems simple (just a couple of boards) but execution is another matter... clearly. Lol!

Comment: To me it sounds like a new screwdriver would be the most cost effective solution.

Comment: Look forward to drawings/etc, but the most obvious thing (if I am understanding correctly) is to attach strips of wood to the fan that run above the fan. In the clear space at the top of those sticks, you can put a screw or two.

Comment: This is what's known as an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Asking about the proposed solution instead of asking for how to solve the problem. :) Pics (including a tape measure/ruler so we can see the space available) will help people come up with workable solutions.

Comment: I'm all set with my photos/drawing....but how do I attach them? LOL!

Comment: From [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/249714/edit) under your question, click the 'Mountain/sun' icon. Pics must be under 2MB. It won't let you inline them, but it will let you upload. Once uploaded, a member with sufficient reputation can inline them for you, [so they become visible rather than just links] Don't try to correct the formatting it generates by yourself.

Comment: Okay, guys!  Tell me what you think I should do (and the type of nails/screws needed during assembly - I know nothing about such things - but do know the right ones are critical when working with wood.  :-) [please see my added text information in my original post and the photos]

Comment: Looks to me like there's holes at the top and bottom of the fan to mount it. Is there any reason you can't rotate the fan so the holes are on each side? If you can, then adding pieces of wood to the sash would allow you to fasten the fan directly into the pieces of wood you added.

Comment: If the motor is at the top, making it top heavy and awkward to mount, install the fan upside down and put the motor at the bottom. Seems that it would be safer that way, no matter where it was mounted.

Comment: If you can wedging styrofoam in the space might be the solution.  If you get it in far enough it will keep any of the outside elements from coming in and make removing the fan in the fall a much easier task.

Answer (score 2):

The extended ledge for the fan to sit on seems reasonable. You should attach thin pieces at the front and back of the fan to prevent the fan from slipping in or out.

Precisely cut styrofoam (closed cell, not open cell) that fits into the channel in the jamb that the sash (sash=the unit that moves) runs in that also wedges the fan sideways. (Aim for 1/16" tight to ensure a good friction fit.)

[image: styrofoam]

The last bit is a length of wood across the top of the fan that fits precisely into the sash channel. It should be about double the width of the sash so that it sticks out in front and offers a place for a couple of screws that anchor the top of the fan. The bottom sash will sit on top of this board and hopefully seal well. If it doesn't, find something to fill the gap. (Sill gasket, backer rod, ...)

[image: board on top]

Happy to clarify if needed.

(Quick edit to say that this setup assumes the lower sash isn't going to get closed when the fan is in place... you might have to adjust the styrofoam a little and make the top board a very tight friction fit for this to work.)

Comment: Interesting, Aloysius!  So the whole unit is held in place by the board on the top?  That would solve the top heavy issue!  (definitely will put a ledge on the bottom.  Only thing is I will want the lower sash to open and close - during inclement weather, since I will be keeping the fan in place all season long. I will need to give a gap of about 1/4" from the window itself.  Interesting. Thanks, much!!

Comment: If you didn't mind a couple of screws into the jamb extensions (to the interior of the sash), you could put a couple of L brackets on the board across the top to keep it in place.

Comment: Another great suggestion, Aloysius!!